How to add a time column that increments based on id column value in pandas?
I have a DataFrame that looks like so-
index    id    name    time     
1        101    A       00:12:00    
2        101    A       00:13:00    
3        101    A       00:14:00    
4        101    A       00:15:00    
.        .      .        .           
.        .      .        .           
59       101    A       01:11:00    
60       101    A       01:12:00    
.        .      .        .           
.        .      .        .           
119      101    A       02:11:00    
120      101    A       02:12:00
121      312    B       00:10:00
122      312    B       00:11:00
123      312    B       00:12:00
.        .      .        .           
.        .      .        .
180      312    B       01:09:00
181      312    B       01:10:00          

What I want to do: Take the DataFrame (say df1), add a new column 'hour' to it which increments whenever the time recorded for the corresponding id passes an hour. This new DataFrame (df2) will be processed further. Below is an example for what df2 would look like-
index    id    name     time        hour
1        101    A       00:12:00    0
2        101    A       00:13:00    0
3        101    A       00:14:00    0
4        101    A       00:15:00    0
.        .      .       .           .
.        .      .       .           .
59       101    A       01:11:00    0
60       101    A       01:12:00    1
.        .      .       .           .
.        .      .       .           .
119      101    A       02:11:00    1
120      101    A       02:12:00    2
121      312    B       00:10:00    0
122      312    B       00:11:00    0
123      312    B       00:12:00    0
.        .      .       .           .       
.        .      .       .           .
180      312    B       01:09:00    0
181      312    B       01:10:00    1

(I'm unable to add a complete and explicit example due to the size but in the unwritten data the hour has the same value as the last written hour value, while the time increments in ticks of 1 min)
Is there any easy way to do this?
I viewed this answer which didn't answer my questions since I'm trying to increment based on time here.
What the columns mean:
id: uniquely identifies the individual
name: name of the individual
time: the time at which the data was recorded
hour: the number of hours for which the id has data for (eg: the first recorded time for id 101 is 00:12:00, which means the hour should increment at 01:12:00, 02:12:00 and so on.
Edit: Removed irrelevant parts of the question

How do you add the new data to the old one?

I'll be creating a new df with the hour column and use it for further processing

Please provide your current code

unfortunately, I have no code helpful to the context of the question

Check if the answer below is what you want, if not please comment and explain why

I just got what you asked by new data, the api provides the updated data again, all of it. So, apologies for the earlier comment. Also to clarify, the hour column increments by 1 when an hour has passed in the time column.

I see, so the existing rows in the new dataset are identical to the old ones?

Yes, they will be. Just one new row per id gets added every time a call is made.

OK, see update in my answer

The solution does not seem to increment the hour column when an hour has passed (the hour increments to 1 when time is 00:15:00 while it should only increment to 1 at 01:12:00). I realize the post lacks context, so I'll be updating it with further info.

Then please provide a meaningful example, there are no hours in your example, also your expected output should match the provided input and be complete (no ...). You're making us guess what you want, which is a waste of time for everyone. Please be explicit.

Break down the computations in your example. For instance why is there a row with 101    A      19       02:12:00  in the output but not in the input? Why is 01:11:00  getting an hour 0?

I'm unsure if it's a formatting mistake on my end but as I can see I've provided the expected output where the 'hour' column increments at 01:12:00. Apologies for the incompleteness of the expected output, I figured it would not be required for me to fill an hour's worth of repeating data

Sorry but the logic is unclear. Where is the value 19 coming from? what are x and y in your output? How many rows exactly would you expect in the output given your provided inputs?

If the dtype of time column is string, then you can use How to calculate the time interval between two time strings. But please provide a complete explicit example, like @mozway is also asking. SO rules require that you do, certainly if you don't post code.

@mozway The periodic updates stated in the question would eventually add up to more than an hour's worth and reach 01:12:00, hence making it part of the input. As for why 01:11:00 has hour 0, it's because 01:11:00 is 59 minutes past 00:12:00 and the hour column should increment once an hour has passed. The 19 is from the value column, which can be any arbitrary integer value given by the api. As for x and y, they're just the index values for some time in the future. I can change them to actual values should you prefer.

@smci sure, I'll do so. I understand that the context I have hasn't been well translated through this post, sorry for that.

@Snak: can you please click edit on the question and add those details? Details down here in comments are not indexed or searchable, also it's ephemeral and liable to get deleted at any point.

Don't provide arbitrary values, provide an explicit example. Given df the original state, new the updated dataset, what is the exact/complete expected output? + add a breakdown of the logic as [edit].

I hope I've made it clearer after removing the irrelevant parts.

Yes, I hope it's clearer, see my update

IIUC, convert to_datetime get the first value per group with groupby.transform then convert to total_seconds and perform a floor division by 3600s:
time = pd.to_datetime(df['time'], format='%H:%M:%S')

df['hour'] = (time.groupby([df['id'], df['name']])
                  .transform('first').rsub(time)
                  .dt.total_seconds().floordiv(3600)
                  .convert_dtypes()
             )

Output:
      id name      time  hour
1    101    A  00:12:00     0
2    101    A  00:13:00     0
3    101    A  00:14:00     0
4    101    A  00:15:00     0
59   101    A  01:11:00     0
60   101    A  01:12:00     1
119  101    A  02:11:00     1
120  101    A  02:12:00     2
121  312    B  00:10:00     0
122  312    B  00:11:00     0
123  312    B  00:12:00     0
180  312    B  01:09:00     0
181  312    B  01:10:00     1

